# How to make user pictures public files?

Tags: files

I need to pass some URLs to user pictures via AJAX. I can't, however, pass **private://filename.jpg** because client can't open it.
Are there some settings to configure where I can change to public space?

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the image field associated with the user profile to Public, and then you need to migrate any existing private image files to the new public directory.  [Here's a write-up on working with files in Drupal 7.](http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/file)

Answer (score 0):

I think you use[`file_create_url()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/file_create_url/7) to turn your URI into a public URL:

```
$path = 'private://test/test.jpg';
print file_create_url($path);
```

The above prints *http://site.com/system/files/test/test.jpg*.

This still means that visiting user should have permission to view that file (as it's a drupal private file).

If thats not true Lester Peabody's answer look good